# how does a flask server validates the form even after returning the html file itself?

Tags: python, flask, flask-wtforms, wtforms

```
@app.route("/register", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def register():
    form = Form()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        pass

    
    return render_template("register.html", form=form)
```

In the above code first there comes the if statement and then the form is returned. So after returning the `render_template("register.html", form=form)`
how does the if statement still validates the form?
whereas after return statement is executed the function should stop running.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: If you submit the form, you make a new request: usually a POST request, with the new data, and you thus rerun the view.

Answer (score 0):

**Make sure you have method "POST" within form-tag in the html.**

```
<form method="POST" action="/register">

    <!-- The internal part of form -->

</form>
```

To see if POST method works you could

```
from flask import request

@app.route("/register", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def register():
    form = Form()

    if request.method == "POST":
        print('It is POST')
        if form.validate_on_submit():
             print('Form validated')

    return render_template("register.html", form=form)
```

---

Then if you get 'It is POST' and not 'Form validated' as the output, then you would need to check your **validators** in the file where you defined Register-Form.